# Unity - Blurry text with dynamic font

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts

For a Unity 2D WEB GL game I'm working on I've imported and used a font which isn't one of Unity's default fonts. I use this font for the text which gets displayed on a canvas. Since my text uses some characters which aren't in the font file, I've set the font character option to dynamic. The result is that the special characters get displayed properly but the text looks quite blurry and not at all sharp.

Now what I want is the text to look sharp, but I've tried pretty much everything I could find with no success. The objects which display the text use a Text Component. I've also tried switching to a TextMeshPro Text Component and generating the font atlas and everything but again to no success.

I've also tried to set the font character type to unicode instead to see what it does (eventhough I know it will not work with my special characters). The result was quite sharper but perhaps too sharp. If I play the game not on full screen mode, some letters are so pixely/crispy they just aren't readable. Thus that wasn't an option either.

I'm at my wits end for this one. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Here's an image example of the blurry font: [image: Blurry font display]

Comment: Get TextMeshPro, and use their FontAssetCreator. Never use Unity's default text component, it's super bad

Comment: Have you tried to increase the reference pixels per unit in the parent canvas scaler?

Comment: @remy_rm I have fiddled with that as well yes, but it didn't make a difference

Comment: @Jichael I've tried using TextMeshProp with the FontAssetCreator but either my implementation was wrong or it didn't work because the font didn't look much better

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a font using textmesh pro. 
Disabled the HDR of the camera component and then it was much better.

Comment: I've just tried it with both HDR on and off but there was no difference between them. The font was still not sharp

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem is to play with Unity `CanvasScaler` component.
This is usually attached to your UI `Canvas`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

You can tweak the values here to get the best result.

Comment: I've tried tweaking those values but nothing I tried had any result. Which options do I need to tweak and to which value do I need to tweak them?

Answer (score 0):

You should increase 'Dynamic Pixels per Unit' on Canvas Scaler